# When do you use an interface over a type alias in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The `interface` and `type` declarations seems to do the same thing. When do you use one over the other?

```
type Fooable = {
  foo(): string
}
```

vs

```
interface Fooable {
 foo(): string
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is a great question. Ideally there would be no difference between an interface and an object type. As implemented, there are a handful of (often subtle) differences between them.

The biggest difference is that Flow considers methods declared on an interface to be "read-only." This allows subtypes to be covariant w.r.t. methods, which is a very common pattern with inheritance hierarchies.

In time, I would like to see Flow unify these concepts, but until then here's my rule of thumb for choosing between interfaces and object types:

- Use object types to describe bags of mostly data that are passed around in your app, e.g., props/state for React components, Flux/Redux actions, JSON-like stuff.
- Use interfaces to describe service-like interfaces. Usually these are mostly methods, e.g., Rx.Observable/Observer, Flux/Redux stores, abstract interfaces. If a class instance is likely to be an inhabitant of your type, you probably want an interface.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you expand on this: `This allows subtypes to be covariant w.r.t. methods`?

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces in Flow can be used to make sure a class implements certain methods and properties. For instance:

```
interface IFly {
   fly(): string
}

// Good!
class Duck implements IFly {
    fly() {
        return "I believe I can fly"
    }
}

// Bad! Cannot implement `IFly` with `Duck` because number is incompatible with string in the return value of property `fly`.
class Duck implements IFly {
    fly() {
        return 42
    }
}

// Bad! Cannot implement `IFly` with `Duck` because property `fly` is missing in `Duck` but exists in `IFly`.
class Duck implements IFly {
    quack() {
        return "quack quack"
    }
}
```

However, if we define an equivalent `IFly` type our `Duck` class won't be able to implement it:

```
type IFly = {
  fly(): string
}

// Cannot implement `Fly` because it is not an interface.
class Duck implements Fly {
    fly() {
       return "I believe I can fly"
    }
}
```

In addition, there are more subtle differences between types and interfaces.

By default, interface properties are **invariant**. For example:

```
interface Foo {
    property: string | number
}

let foo: Foo = { property: 42 } // Cannot assign object literal to `foo` because number is incompatible with string in property `property`.
```

To make interface property **covariant** they need to be made read-only:

```
interface Foo {
    +property: string | number
}

let foo: Foo = { property: 42 } // Good!
```

With types, on the other hand, Flow will not complain:

```
type Foo = {
    property: string | number
}

// Good!
let foo: Foo = { property: 42 }
```

References:

1. [Flow interfaces](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only-)
2. [Type variance](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/)